# GNOME 3 desktop entry duplicate

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome3

Was trying to get simple desktop entry to work without creating duplicated after app run.

That's for st3 under GNOME3 (Fedora 19), and `.desktop` file looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=3.047
Type=Application
Name=Sublime Text 3
Icon=path-to-logo.png
Exec="path-to-exec" %f
Comment=some comment
Categories=Editor;Text;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=Sublime_text
```

Thought that "StartupWMClass" key will do the job of grouping windows in a dock, but it does not. Looks like I've missed something.

I got wmclass with xprop WMCLASS:

```
[me@pc ~]$ xprop WM_CLASS
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "sublime_text", "Sublime_text"
```

Example:

[image]

Desktop entry is at the top (ye, another logo file), but app is not get grouped in it and is shown separately. Any way to fix it?

Thanx for help!

**UPDATE:**
I've changed .desktop entry to:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Sublime Text 3
StartupNotify=true
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Edit text files
Exec="/usr/local/bin/sublime_text_3/sublime_text" %U
MimeType=text/plain;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-java;text/x-dsrc;text/x-pascal;text/x-perl;text/x-python;application/x-php;application/x-httpd-php3;application/x-httpd-php4;application/x-httpd-php5;application/xml;text/html;text/css;text/x-sql;text/x-diff;x-directory/normal;inode/directory;
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;TextEditor;Application;Development;
Icon=/usr/local/bin/sublime_text_3/st3_custom_logo.png
Name[en_US]=Sublime Text 3
```

(found on the st forum)

Everything is fine now. Don't understand how it works though, thought that WMClass is how windows are grouped.

Comment: So, I'm guessing the addition of the `MimeType` resolved the issue on your system with the "Sublime" text editor?

Do you follow the same procedure for other applications on your system with same issues? I noticed the "WMClass" entry is missing altogether.  This freedesktop classification stuff is confusing as hell! :(

Comment: Running into the same exact problem. Using your updated .desktop entry hasn't resolved it at all. The odd thing is, I got it working before, but now it has stopped working, without a change to the .desktop file. The only thing i can think of is that I recently started working in a sublime project, but closing that project hasn't made a difference.

Comment: Is this a bug in GNOME 3.8? https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/32982/duplicate-icon-on-gnome-dock-when-running-eclipse/